# How to make a copy of trigger function in postgreSQL pgadmin 4?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, pgadmin-4

I am using postgreSQL with pgAdmin 4 and I have created a database function named "`fn_test1()`". I want to delete this function and before delete this function, I want to create a backup function named "`fn_test1_bk()`" . Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: It is really a shame that people spend all that time writing documentation that no one bothers to read. [Alter Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterfunction.html). `ALTER FUNCTION name [ ( [ [ argmode ] [ argname ] argtype [, ...] ] ) ]
    RENAME TO new_name`. There is even an example at bottom of page.  Kills two birds with one stone.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use PgAdmin for this, you can browse to your function, right click, properties, change the name and save.

[image]

[image]